# Using rqt_rviz with custom .rviz config

Tags: rviz, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We’re planning to use rqt_rviz as part of a laymen-facing robot GUI. The current plan is to create a .rviz configuration for RViz that limits what ROS stuff the user sees and then use rqt_rviz with additional rqt plugins to provide an integrated UI. Ideally the RViz menu bar would not be visible to the user either.

Is it possible to load the rqt_rviz plugin with an RViz config file? Also, is there an easy way to remove the menu bar from the rqt_rviz plugin?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/98126/using-rqt_rviz-with-custom-.rviz-config/) by [abencz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1851/abencz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2013-11-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Answered my own question by looking at the code :P

No it's not possible at the moment to do this from a script/launch file, rqt_rviz initializes the RViz frame with no configuration file argument at all. However, if you're willing to modify the rqt_rviz C++ code, it's a trivial matter of adding a filename (or better yet a ros parameter) as an argument to `_widget->initialize()` in `RViz::initPlugin`. Likewise the menu bar can be removed by deleting the call to `_widget->setMenuBar()`.

```
void RViz::initPlugin(qt_gui_cpp::PluginContext& context)
{
  context_ = &context;

  // prevent output of Ogre stuff to console
  Ogre::LogManager* log_manager = Ogre::LogManager::getSingletonPtr();
  if (!log_manager)
  {
    log_manager = new Ogre::LogManager();
  }
  QString filename = QString("rqt_rviz_ogre") + (context.serialNumber() > 1 ? QString::number(context.serialNumber()) : QString("")) + QString(".log");
  log_ = log_manager->createLog(filename.toStdString().c_str(), false, false);

  widget_ = new rviz::VisualizationFrame();

  // create own menu bar to disable native menu bars on Unity and Mac
  QMenuBar* menu_bar = new QMenuBar();
  menu_bar->setNativeMenuBar(false);
  //widget_->setMenuBar(menu_bar);

  widget_->initialize("my_config.rviz");

  ...
```

---

Originally posted by [abencz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1851/abencz/) with karma: 83 on 2013-11-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [flynneva](https://answers.ros.org/users/44351/flynneva/) on 2019-08-19**:
can we get this added into the main branch for rqt_rviz? this is an extremely useful enhancement

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-08-20**:
You're posting a comment on an answered question that is over 6 years old. That is not a good way to draw attention to this.

If this isn't already supported in `rqt_rviz`, then the quickest way to get it in is to submit a Pull Request.